# admob publisher id my ad unit id

Tags: android, android-intent, admob

what is my admob publisher id?  MY_AD_UNIT_ID and TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID

ca-app-pub-193**********/67*******

```
     <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

???

Comment: I actually asked admob banner id to add ad to my app but i found it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start is a good tutorial, it explains everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use the latest admob version provided by google play services..

However, your ad unit id is in your admob app profile and the test device id is printed for you in the logcat console once you run the app, then you can use it and start debugging.

Comment: I solved them but when I run the program despite no error, it does not work.

Comment: you should provide more info